# Scrolling in Drawer Layout Android

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, android-scrollview

I have been trying to implement Navigation Drawer in Android. It contains a imageView Layout, two listviews and some other views. But, in smaller screens, I should add a scollView so that full drawer can be scrolled and seen.

The layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_LinearLayout_left"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/orange_transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp" >

        <com.app.RoundImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View Account"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/locationButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Choose location" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MORE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#DADADC" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But, after adding scroll view, each listview gets limited to a single element list with scrolling functionality in it.

The layout file for the drawer after adding scrollView is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_Leftdrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_LinearLayout_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp" >

            <com.app.RoundImageView
                android:id="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/name_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="View Account"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/locationButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Choose location" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_more"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MORE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#DADADC" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help how can I add scroll view to full drawer.

Comment: If you put ScrollView as the first view in your xml, does it work ? Before the frameLayout

Comment: you cant use listview inside a scrollview. how would the app know which view to scroll then. I don't know how many items will be in the listview but if its not that many just create the views your since you already a scrollview.

Comment: Thanks, I got this. I instead constructed a custom view.